# Field#getGenericType() throws java.lang.TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, maven, reflection, annotations

I have a Maven plugin I am writing where I need to know the type of the  `List<Person>` where `Person` is an object defined within a dependency. This plugin runs during the`process-classes` phase to generate some files from what it finds on annotated classes within the host project. In this case the host project contains references to libraries within other projects which are included as Maven dependencies.

The `Person` class:

```
package com.dependency.models;    

public class Person {
    // Irrelevent
}
```

The use within the class I am performing the query on:

```
package com.project.wrappers;

import com.dependency.Person;    

@MyAnnotation
public class Wrapper {
     List<Person> people;
     // Other irrelevant stuff
}
```

The annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

From within a Maven plugin use context I load all the `Wrapper` objects via annotation and then process. To do this I need to use a custom classloader via the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library:

```
public static Set<Class<?>> findAnnotatedClasses(MavenProject mavenProject, Class<? extends Annotation> input) throws MojoExecutionException {
    List<String> classpathElements = null;

    try {
        classpathElements = mavenProject.getCompileClasspathElements();
        List<URL> projectClasspathList = new ArrayList<URL>();
        for (String element : classpathElements) {
            Application.getLogger().debug("Considering compile classpath element (via MavenProject): " + element);
            try {
                projectClasspathList.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new MojoExecutionException(element + " is an invalid classpath element", e);
            }
        }

        // Retain annotations
        JavassistAdapter javassistAdapter = new JavassistAdapter();
        javassistAdapter.includeInvisibleTag = false;

        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(projectClasspathList.toArray(new URL[]{}),
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(
                        ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(urlClassLoader)
                ).addClassLoader(urlClassLoader).setScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), new TypeElementsScanner(),
                        new FieldAnnotationsScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), new SubTypesScanner(false)
                ).setMetadataAdapter(javassistAdapter)
        );

        return findAnnotatedClasses(reflections, input);

    } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException("Dependency resolution failed", e);
    }
}
```

Everything up to here works great. But if I try the following, within my parser, it fails:

```
Field field = Wrapper.class.getDeclaredField("people");
ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
Class<?> listTypeClass = (Class<?>) listType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.dependency.models.Person not present
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.getGenericType(FieldRepository.java:85)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType(Field.java:247)
```

Which if one follows further:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dependency.models.Person
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
```

Which means that my classloading is working for everything prior to this last step. I think I need a way to override the classloader used within the `sun.reflect` library but it may not be possible. Any recommendations on a better approach?

**UPDATE**

I have added the dependency jars to a `URLClassLoader` and am attempting to override the current classloader which is being used by the above `CoreReflectionFactory` to no avail.

Comment: When you are capable of writing `Wrapper.class`, it means that the class `Wrapper` has been loaded through the class loader that loaded your code (or one of its parents), but not through your custom class loader. For the JVM, there is no reason for resolving dependencies of that class through an unrelated custom class loader. But why is the `Person` class not available in that context when it was when `Wrapper` was compiled?

Comment: @Holger Because `Person` is located within a dependency. I can load it with the custom ClassLoader no problem but the `CoreReflectionFactory` does not use the custom ClassLoader. It uses the default system classloader which cannot be overriden (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I got a similar issue and it was resolved by reloading the whole Gradle project (Not elegant at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not to just add the dependencies to the classloader but to actually resolve the jar paths and then add the path of those jars to the classpath for the reflections library to include it in their scanning.

So, get all the artifacts from Maven and then resolve and add each path to Reflections when building that piece. Something like this:

```
public static URL[] buildProjectClasspathList(ArtifactReference artifactReference)  throws ArtifactResolutionException, MalformedURLException, DependencyResolutionRequiredException {

    List<URL> projectClasspathList = new ArrayList<URL>();

    // Load build class path
    if(classpathElementsCache == null) {
        Application.getLogger().debug("Compile Classpath Elements Cache was null; fetching update");
        classpathElementsCache = artifactReference.getMavenProject().getCompileClasspathElements();
    }

    for (String element : classpathElementsCache) {
        Application.getLogger().debug("Looking at compile classpath element (via MavenProject): " + element);
        Application.getLogger().debug("  Adding: " + element);
        projectClasspathList.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
    }

    // Load artifact(s) jars using resolver
    if(dependencyArtifactsCache == null) {
        Application.getLogger().debug("Dependency Artifacts Cache was null; fetching update");
        dependencyArtifactsCache =  artifactReference.getMavenProject().getDependencyArtifacts();
    }

    Application.getLogger().debug("Number of artifacts to resolve: "
            + dependencyArtifactsCache.size());

    for (Artifact unresolvedArtifact : dependencyArtifactsCache) {
        String artifactId = unresolvedArtifact.getArtifactId();

        if (!isArtifactResolutionRequired(unresolvedArtifact, artifactReference)) {
            Application.getLogger().debug("  Skipping: " + unresolvedArtifact.toString());
            continue;
        }

        org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact aetherArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(
                unresolvedArtifact.getGroupId(),
                unresolvedArtifact.getArtifactId(),
                unresolvedArtifact.getClassifier(),
                unresolvedArtifact.getType(),
                unresolvedArtifact.getVersion());

        ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest()
                .setRepositories(artifactReference.getRepositories())
                .setArtifact(aetherArtifact);

        // This takes time; minimizing what needs to be resolved is the goal of the specified dependency code block
        ArtifactResult resolutionResult = artifactReference.getRepoSystem()
                .resolveArtifact(artifactReference.getRepoSession(), artifactRequest);

        // The file should exist, but we never know.
        File file = resolutionResult.getArtifact().getFile();
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
            Application.getLogger().warn("Artifact " + artifactId +
                    " has no attached file. Its content will not be copied in the target model directory.");
            continue;
        }

        String jarPath = "jar:file:" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "!/";
        Application.getLogger().debug("Adding resolved artifact: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        projectClasspathList.add(new URL(jarPath));
    }

    return projectClasspathList.toArray(new URL[]{});
}
```

Where `ArtifactReference` includes the MavenProject and Repo objects:

```
public class ArtifactReference {
    private MavenProject mavenProject;
    private RepositorySystem repoSystem;
    private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;
    private List<RemoteRepository> repositories;
    private List<String> specifiedDependencies;
}
```